# [VBA]Error while making ADO query in MS Access with linked table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ado

Error #-2147467259
   ODBC--call failed.
   (Source: Microsoft JET Database Engine)
   (SQL State: 3146)
   (NativeError: -532940753)
   No Help file available

What happened? What is the reason of this? **I can make a query to a different sql server via odbc linked table(uat env), but when I go to prod server, this error come out.**

I am using ms access 2000, and built a form within it, then make a query to the server when a button was pressed. The prod server get A LOT of records, while the uat server only have 3000 records, however I don't think that is a problem...

Thank to any possible help!!

This is the part of the queries:

```
Sub extractInboundCdr()
On Error GoTo Error_Handling
   Dim conConnection As New ADODB.Connection
   Dim cmdCommand As New ADODB.Command
   Dim rstRecordSet As New ADODB.Recordset
   Dim Err As ADODB.Error
   Dim strError As String


   Dim eventPlanCode As String
   Dim visitedCountry As String
   Dim startDateTxt As String
   Dim startDate As Date
   Dim endDate As Date
   Dim imsi As String
   Dim currentMonth As String
   Dim nextMonth As String
   Dim currentYear As String
   Dim nextYear As String
   Dim temp As Integer
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim j As Integer

   With conConnection
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = CurrentDb.Name
    .Open
   End With
   conConnection.CommandTimeout = 0

   With cmdCommand
    .ActiveConnection = conConnection
    .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Opt_In_Customer_Record;"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
   End With

   With rstRecordSet
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open cmdCommand
   End With

   If rstRecordSet.EOF = False Then
        rstRecordSet.MoveFirst
        Do
            eventPlanCode = rstRecordSet!Event_Plan_Code
            visitedCountry = rstRecordSet!Visited_Country
            startDateTxt = rstRecordSet!start_date
            imsi = rstRecordSet!imsi
            currentMonth = Mid$(startDateTxt, 1, 3)
            currentYear = Mid$(startDateTxt, 8, 4)


            nextMonth = ""
            If (currentMonth = "Jan") Then
                currentMonth = "01"
                nextMonth = "02"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "Feb") Then
                currentMonth = "02"
                nextMonth = "03"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "Mar") Then
                currentMonth = "03"
                nextMonth = "04"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "Apr") Then
                currentMonth = "04"
                nextMonth = "05"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "May") Then
                currentMonth = "05"
                nextMonth = "06"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "Jun") Then
                currentMonth = "06"
                nextMonth = "07"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "Jul") Then
                currentMonth = "07"
                nextMonth = "08"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "Aug") Then
                currentMonth = "08"
                nextMonth = "09"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "Sep") Then
                currentMonth = "09"
                nextMonth = "10"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "Oct") Then
                currentMonth = "10"
                nextMonth = "11"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "Nov") Then
                currentMonth = "11"
                nextMonth = "12"
            ElseIf (currentMonth = "Dec") Then
                currentMonth = "12"
                nextMonth = "01"
            Else
                GoTo Error_Handling
            End If

            temp = Val(currentYear)
            temp = temp + 1
            nextYear = CStr(temp)

            Exit Do
        Loop Until rstRecordSet.EOF = True
   End If


   Set cmdCommand = Nothing
   Set rstRecordSet = Nothing
   Set connConnection = Nothing

   With conConnection
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = CurrentDb.Name
    .Open
   End With
   conConnection.CommandTimeout = 0

   Dim thisMonthTable As String
   Dim nextMonthTable As String

   thisMonthTable = "dbo_inbound_rated_all_" & currentYear & currentMonth

   If (currentMonth = "12") Then
        nextMonthTable = "dbo_inbound_rated_all_" & nextYear & nextMonth
   Else
        nextMonthTable = "dbo_inbound_rated_all_" & currentYear & nextMonth
   End If

   With cmdCommand
    .ActiveConnection = conConnection
    .CommandText = "(SELECT A.IMSI_NUMBER, A.CALL_DATE, A.CALL_TIME, A.VOL_KBYTE, A.TOTAL_CHARGE ,datevalue(A.call_date), A.Service_Code As theDate FROM " & thisMonthTable & " AS A INNER JOIN Opt_In_Customer_Record AS B on A.imsi_number = B.imsi where A.Service_Code = 'GPRS' and Datevalue(A.call_date) >= Datevalue(B.start_date) And Datevalue(A.call_date) < (Datevalue(B.start_date) + val(LEFT(B.event_plan_code, 1))) ) " & _
                   "UNION " & _
                   "(SELECT A.IMSI_NUMBER, A.CALL_DATE, A.CALL_TIME, A.VOL_KBYTE, A.TOTAL_CHARGE ,datevalue(A.call_date), A.Service_Code As theDate FROM " & nextMonthTable & " AS A INNER JOIN Opt_In_Customer_Record AS B on A.imsi_number = B.imsi where A.Service_Code = 'GPRS' and Datevalue(A.call_date) >= Datevalue(B.start_date) And Datevalue(A.call_date) < (Datevalue(B.start_date) + val(LEFT(B.event_plan_code, 1))) ) " & _
                   "Order by A.IMSI_NUMBER, theDate"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
   End With

   With rstRecordSet
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockReadOnly
    .Open cmdCommand
   End With


   If rstRecordSet.EOF = False Then
        rstRecordSet.MoveFirst
        Do
            Dim sql As String
            sql = "insert into IB_CDR values ("

            For j = 0 To rstRecordSet.Fields.Count - 3 '''''Last 2 fields is not inserted
                If (j = 3 Or j = 4) Then '''''These fields are number
                    sql = sql & rstRecordSet.Fields(j) & ","
                Else
                    sql = sql & "'" & rstRecordSet.Fields(j) & "',"
                End If
            Next


            sql = Left(sql, Len(sql) - 1) '''''Remove the last ','
            sql = sql & ");"

            CurrentDb.Execute sql

            rstRecordSet.MoveNext

        Loop Until rstRecordSet.EOF = True
   End If



   conConnection.Close
   Set conConnection = Nothing
   Set cmdCommand = Nothing
   Set rstRecordSet = Nothing

   Exit Sub

Error_Handling:
For Each Err In conConnection.Errors
        strError = "Error #" & Err.Number & vbCr & _
            "   " & Err.Description & vbCr & _
            "   (Source: " & Err.Source & ")" & vbCr & _
            "   (SQL State: " & Err.SQLState & ")" & vbCr & _
            "   (NativeError: " & Err.NativeError & ")" & vbCr
        If Err.HelpFile = "" Then
            strError = strError & "   No Help file available"
        Else
            strError = strError & _
               "   (HelpFile: " & Err.HelpFile & ")" & vbCr & _
               "   (HelpContext: " & Err.HelpContext & ")" & _
               vbCr & vbCr
        End If

        Debug.Print strError
    Next

    Resume Next
Set conConnection = Nothing
Set cmdCommand = Nothing
Set rstRecordSet = Nothing
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The most common cause of this error is incorrect permissions on the folder containing the Access database.  You will need to set write permissions.

Comment: Do you mean the mdb file of the access program?

Comment: I mean the FOLDER that contains the MDB file (as well as the MDB file itself).

Comment: The permisson is full-control for everyone already. Also the mdb have full-control for everyone.

Comment: Next most common is a permissions error on the SQL Server. This is hinted at when OP says it works on different server but throws error on Prod.

Comment: I think this answer is completely mistaken. How in the world could permissions on the MDB front end produce an ODBC error from the SQL Server?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton - My answer was only a guess based on experience with this particular error.  Write permissions are needed on the MDB file so that the database can be modified, and write permissions are needed on the folder itself so that a lock file (LDB) can be created.  That being said, my guess is probably wrong because the OP said that "everyone" already has "full control."

Comment: Well, it still couldn't produce an ODBC error, since the permissions involved are entirely in the file system. I'll hold off on downvoting to give you a chance to edit out "the most common cause of this error" assertion. ODBC errors are almost never going to be caused by file permissions errors, let along commonly.